Error 500.30 after changing target platform from x64 to x86 in a Web Server API project in Visual Studio 2022
I've created a new Web Server API project in Visual Studio 2022 using .NET 8.0. Automatically, the WeatherForecast controller is generated. After compiling and publishing without making any changes, I configured the project on IIS, and everything works fine.
Later, I changed the target platform to x86.

I compiled and published again without receiving any errors. I also tried setting the runtime target to x86 and x64.

However, after configuring the project on IIS, I'm getting a 500.30 error when trying to access the created controller.

When I run the project in Debug/Release mode directly from Visual Studio, everything works fine.
After enabling logging, I receive this error:

Event Log: 'Application '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\restapi' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.'
End Event Log Message.

Can someone help me resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Did you try to change the application pool to run in 32 bit?

'thank you very much, that was exactly the problem

Expand my comment a little bit.
You probably already know that ASP.NET Core by default uses in-process hosting mode. IIS by default creates 64 bit worker processes (w3wp.exe) which in turn loads the 64 bit ASP.NET Core module (ANCM, aka aspnetcorev2.dll).
ANCM loads Any CPU/x64 bits without problems, as bitness matches. However, you intentionally changed your artifacts to 32 bit, which cannot be loaded in 64 bit processes. That's the cause of the 500.30 error.
There is usually no reason to switch to 32 bit, but if you do have a need you have to also change IIS application pool to run in 32 bit mode, so that it creates 32 bit worker process with 32 bit ANCM. That's how you found the error was resolved.

Perfect explanation, thank you. I need to run at 32 bits because I have to use a 32-bit dll. To solve the issue, all I had to do was to enable 32-bit applications for the user in the pool. For example, as shown in this guide https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/1467/IIS-7-and-IIS-8-Enable-32-bit-Applications-in-Application-Pool-of-IIS-Server/

I suggest you to look at the event viewer to try to identify the exact reason.
HTTP Error 500 is caused by an exception at run-time. So there could be many reason. Sometimes, you must look at the 2 or 3 events before till 2 or 3 events after.
In order, I would search on:

The runtime. Is it well set up on the server. You have to install the
bundle
(https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-8.0.4-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)
The necessary libraries. If you have published the application,
everything is located in the bin\publish folder.
The permissions that are affected to the folder. To be sure, you can add 'Everyone' to the list of authorized users, and give Read/Write permission. It the problem is solved, you will have to give the exact permissions which are determined by the Application Pool that serves this web site.

Also, if you didn't find at this stage, you can start the .exe file of your application instead of IIS which will run in a console and will show you the exceptions if any. You must stop the web site before running the exe.
Good luck.

While there can be several causes of 500.30, this question itself clearly points to the actual cause, bitness mismatch.
